# Views not found on disabling Page Title module

Tags: 7, debugging

I've  Views 7.x-3.7 and Page Title 7.x-2.7 installed. Since many months I'm using Meta tags and Page Title module but now I want to remove Page Title module as I don't need it since Metatag module provides equivalent functionality.

But on disabling Page Title module I'm getting **page not found(404)** for the Views Page display URL. Also when I go to edit that display in the View from Structure->Views I get the following screen:

> [image]

When I go to view the Page url of the View Display I get this :

> [image]

There is no information in the dblog except for this when I access the View Page url:

> [image]

**What should I check to start debugging this?**

Comment: Do u uninstall page title completely? do u clear cache after uninstall?

Comment: Yes I've reinstalled Page Title 2 times. Cleared all cache many times. But nothing worked.

Comment: I dont completely understand what you are trying to do, but page title module doesn't consists [predefined views at all](http://drupalcode.org/project/page_title.git/tree).
Maybe it's part of another module that refers to page title?

Answer (score 0):

The page_titles module sets a lot of variables. I don't know if that would cause an issue like you are seeing, but it's best to remove these variables. Disabling the module will not remove them, but uninstalling it will. With page_title disabled, go to admin/modules/uninstall, select the module, and click uninstall. This will unset all variables that were set by the module.

Comment: I've tried uninstalling Page Title twice already.

Comment: I just noticed in dblog the message is 'views/advanced-search-1-.htm. Does the path of the page view end in .htm? If so, that might tell apache to look for a file and things will get weird! I would export the view, copy the code, search for "'path'", and remove any extension. Then you can re-import with the override view with same name option checked. From your screenshot it looks like the view doesn't even have the dropdown "edit view/name description" to select export. In which case, go to admin/structure/views/view/advanced_search_1_/export.